# Why imperative pod creation doesn't have 'kubectl create'?

Tags: kubectl

You can create service, deployment etc using `kubectl create` but you can't with a pod. You need to use `kubectl run` instead. What may be the reason for this? You technical create pod with `kubectl run --generator=run-pod/v1` anyway isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only hypothesise that this was kind of an arbitrary decision, not a technical one.

As of kubectl 1.16, `kubectl create` can create the following types of resources:

```
clusterrole, clusterrolebinding, configmap, cronjob, deployment, job,
namespace, poddisruptionbudget, priorityclass, quota, role, rolebinding,
secret, service, serviceaccount
```

As you can see, these are all resource types that are typically used in a standalone way. For example, it's common to directly create a Deployment or a Job. However, it's not common to directly create a Pod for running workloads, and it is [not recommended](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.16/#pod-v1-core) (there are exceptions but they are mainly for debugging and management tasks). Instead, Pods should only be created as part of a Deployment, Job, etc.

Given that, and that the [imperative kubectl commands](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/imperative-command/) were initially designed for beginners, the kubectl team may have decided to not include Pods in `kubectl create`. Also, they just needed to draw the line somewhere, i.e., you can only include the most common resource types in `kubectl create`, otherwise the list would become really long.

The way to run a single Pod is `kubectl run --generator=run-pod/v1`.